Unity isometric Tilemap / Tile Palette: Exact asset placement
just starting out in Unity.
I tried to include a tile asset into an isometric tile palette. However, I can't manage to make its size match exactly one tile of the grid all while perfectly covering it. On paper it works without aligning with the grid but this announces hell for later.
Grid Cell Size: 1 / 0.5 / 1
Palette Cell Size: 1 / 0.5 / 1
Image Size of the asset: 128 x 128
Pixels Per Unit: 128
With PPU 128: the asset seems too large and is shown below the grid.
With PPU 256: places the asset precisely onto the grid as wished but is 4 times too small
What would be the necessary setting that I overlooked or messed up?
With PPU: 128 
With PPU: 256 

it looks like the difference between a corner pivot and a center pivot on 128 for me

Indeed, setting pivot to bottom right or bottom left seem the most correct (I had center). However, the asset appears a cell next to the chosen cell which doesn't seem ideal, and might causes headaches later. Is this normal, or should you easily be able to place asset with pivot = center?

I guess in part it depends how you assign them.

It's not clear what you mean. I just drag the image into the Tile Palette, selecting a certain cell, and no matter the pivot, the asset won't be placed precisely onto the targeted cell
